# Drawing a set number of stairs

Tags: python

I have to write a program to ask the user for how many steps to draw. The user will always enter an integer greater than zero. For example, if the user entered 4, the program should output:

```
How many steps? 4
__
  |_
    |_
      |_
________|
​
```

The horizontal lines are created using underscores (_) and the vertical lines using the pipe character (|). Here is another example interaction between the program and the user:

```
How many steps? 1
__
__|
```

i tried this but it doesn't work

```
num_steps = int(input("How many steps? "))

if num_steps>0:
  print("__")
  print((" " * 2)+"|")
  for i in range(num_steps):
    print(" " * (i+2) + "_" + "|"  )

  print("_"*(i+5)
```

Comment: sorry I don't see a logic in the drawn stairs. the number of underscores seems random. In the case of 4steps, there are 2 underscores, then 1, then 1 and then 1 with a space followed by many underscores. Could you explain the logic?

Comment: Why do you **have** to do this?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can try:

```py
n = 4

print("__")
for s in range(n):
    last_step = s == n - 1
    print(
        ((s + last_step) * 2) * ("_" if last_step else " ")
        + "  " * (not last_step)
        + "|"
        + ("" if last_step else "_")
    )
```

Prints:

```
__
  |_
    |_
      |_
________|
```

For `n=1`:

```
__
__|
```

For `n=10`:

```
__
  |_
    |_
      |_
        |_
          |_
            |_
              |_
                |_
                  |_
____________________|
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working solution, hope it might help:

```
num_steps = int(input("How many steps? "))

if num_steps > 0:
    print("_")
    print((" ") + "|")
    if num_steps > 1:
        for i in range(1,num_steps):
            print(" " * (i + i) + "_")
            print(" " * (i + i + 1) + "|")
    else:
        i = 0
    print("_" * (i + i + 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Every step except the last one is an indented `"  |_"` string.  you can print those in a loop and add the final one (with leading underscores) at the end of the loop:

Here is what the code could look like:

```
num_steps = int(input("How many steps? "))

if num_steps>0:
    print( "__")
    for i in range(num_steps-1):
        print("  "*i+"  |_")
    print("__"*num_steps+"|")
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is similar with a few differences:

```
num_steps = int(input("How many steps? "))

if num_steps > 0:
  print("__")
  print((" " * 2)+"|" + "_")
  for i in range(num_steps-2):
    print("  " * (i+2) + "|_" )

  print("__"*(num_steps) +"|")
```